# Convert the following jsonElement to joda DateTime using custom deserializer

Tags: json, datetime, gson, jodatime, json-deserialization

I have a JsonElement {"iMillis":1465936837501,"iChronology":{"iBase":{"iMinDaysInFirstWeek":4}}}. I want to deserialize it to joda DateTime.

I am trying to use custom deserializer:

```
class DateTimeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<DateTime> {
    public DateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        return new DateTime(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString());
    }
}
```

But this gives me error that given json is not a json primitive.
I have also tried direct json.getAsString() but that gives an UnsupportedOperationException error.

Can anyone help me with this de-serialization?

Thanks!